# Drupal SQL timeout error

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I keep randomly getting this error within my Drupal site. Only way to resolve is to delete the session from the database.

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction: SELECT revision.order_number AS order_number, revision.revision_id AS revision_id, revision.revision_uid AS revision_uid, revision.mail AS mail, revision.status AS status, revision.log AS log, revision.revision_timestamp AS revision_timestamp, revision.revision_hostname AS revision_hostname, revision.data AS data, base.order_id AS order_id, base.type AS type, base.uid AS uid, base.created AS created, base.changed AS changed, base.hostname AS hostname FROM {commerce_order} base INNER JOIN {commerce_order_revision} revision ON revision.revision_id = base.revision_id WHERE (base.order_id IN (:db_condition_placeholder_0)) FOR UPDATE; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 1 ) in DrupalDefaultEntityController->load() (line 196 of C:\Sites\includes\entity.inc).

Do you have any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sessions` table has been known to get corrupted, try running a `REPAIR TABLE sessions` query against your database.

Comment: I see, seems to have worked for now.. It started happening when introduced the commerce module..

Comment: @clockworkworks: On closer inspection is seems to be a [reported bug](http://drupal.org/node/1320062)...no fix as yet :(

Comment: spoke too soon is still doin it.... has somehing to do with (line 196 of C:\Sites\includes\entity.inc).

Comment: well at least i know it isnt me ha. im thinking maybe should just use Ubercart then for the time being? until a fix comes up.... would you reccomend this? Thanks again Clive

Comment: I would recommend Ubercart 110%, I've used Commerce and Ubercart for Drupal 7 and Commerce just isn't mature enough yet in my humble opinion (or at least the add-on modules aren't). I'm currently developing several Ubercart 7 sites, and have one in production as well and they're all working great

Comment: Awesome advice! It seems like it is a lot more stable. Is it possible in drupal to allow a autheticated user to have their own subsite? ie/ user called jake could have http://jake.example.com??? With their own ubercart etc etc. Sorry for all th questions but your wisdom is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's possible definitely but it'd take some pretty heavy custom coding, I'm not aware of any existing modules that would do this automatically (I could well be wrong though there are a lot of them!). The [Domain Access module](http://drupal.org/project/domain) and [Subdomain module](http://drupal.org/project/subdomain) spring to mind as a place you might look to start though

Comment: @Clive hello to master clive, really you are fantastic in drupal, I ad this error in one of my customers site,first I try your solution and work,but it occur again, I found the patch and apply it, https://www.drupal.org/node/1320062#pift-results-1320062
and waiting to future results,
what is better, repair session table each day or week or this patch?

Comment: If it works, I'd say the patch is the better @zhilevan. Less manual maintenance. If you don't already, consider keeping a file listing any core/contrib patches somewhere easily accessible to anyone who works on the site - that way there's less chance of something getting messed up when you or another dev come to update it in the future

Comment: @Clive I keep all patched in a directory, tnx for your reply :)